# Scaling a ratingBar in a listview causes a leftward shift. How to get the ratingBar back to the right edge?

Tags: android, xml, listview

I have a listView with two rating bars which are using a 50x50 pixel image and has to be re-sized to 50% original size to fit both on the right side of a single row. However when re-sizing it shifts the rating Bars to the left away from the edge of the row where I would like them to be. Any help is greatly appreciated as I have looked over this site and others to no avail.

```
...

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">

<RatingBar
        style="@style/sodaRatingBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:scaleX="0.5"
        android:scaleY="0.5"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:indeterminateOnly="false" />

...
```

If you need a picture I can supply a screencap. Also, I could resize the star images I am using in the rating bar but I thought that the standard android size was around 50x50.

Comment: Here is a screen cap of the issue, http://imgur.com/31yc4FO . As you can see there is a bit of space to the right of the ratingBars. Also, just using a placeholder image.

Comment: Are you resizing the `Ratingbars` in code?

Comment: Resizing via the scaleX, scaleY in the xml. I could try doing it in code.

Comment: What happens if you use only one `RatingBar`? And what about if you set `android:layout_width="match_parent"` to your `LinearLayout`?